# How to compute minimal but fast linear regressions on each column of a response matrix?

Tags: algorithm, r, optimization, linear-regression, least-squares

I want to compute ordinary least square (**OLS**) estimates in R **without using "lm"**, and this for several reasons. First, "lm" also computes lots of stuff I don't need (such as the fitted values) considering that data size is an issue in my case. Second, I want to be able to implement OLS myself in R before doing it in another language (eg. in C with the GSL).

As you may know, the **model** is: Y=Xb+E; with E ~ N(0, sigma^2). As detailed below, b is a vector with 2 parameters, the mean (b0) and another coefficients (b1). At the end, for each linear regression I will do, I want the estimate for b1 (effect size), its standard error, the estimate for sigma^2 (residual variance), and R^2 (determination coef).

Here are my **data**. I have N samples (eg. individuals, N~=100). For each sample, I have Y outputs (response variables, Y~=10^3) and X points (explanatory variables, X~=10^6). I want to treat the Y outputs separately, ie. I want to launch Y linear regressions: one for output 1, one for output 2, etc. Moreover, I want to use explanatory variables one y one: for output 1, I want to regress it on point 1, then on point 2, then ... finally on point X. (I hope it's clear...!)

Here is my **R code** to check the speed of "lm" versus computing OLS estimates myself via matrix algebra.

First, I simulate dummy data:

```
nb.samples <-  10  # N
nb.points <- 1000  # X
x <- matrix(data=replicate(nb.samples,sample(x=0:2,size=nb.points, replace=T)),
            nrow=nb.points, ncol=nb.samples, byrow=F,
            dimnames=list(points=paste("p",seq(1,nb.points),sep=""),
              samples=paste("s",seq(1,nb.samples),sep="")))
nb.outputs <- 10  # Y
y <- matrix(data=replicate(nb.outputs,rnorm(nb.samples)),
            nrow=nb.samples, ncol=nb.outputs, byrow=T,
            dimnames=list(samples=paste("s",seq(1,nb.samples),sep=""),
              outputs=paste("out",seq(1,nb.outputs),sep="")))
```

Here is my own function used just below:

```
GetResFromCustomLinReg <- function(Y, xi){ # both Y and xi are N-dim vectors
  n <- length(Y)
  X <- cbind(rep(1,n), xi)  #
  p <- 1      # nb of explanatory variables, besides the mean
  r <- p + 1  # rank of X: nb of indepdt explanatory variables
  inv.XtX <- solve(t(X) %*% X)
  beta.hat <- inv.XtX %*% t(X) %*% Y
  Y.hat <- X %*% beta.hat
  E.hat <- Y - Y.hat
  E2.hat <- (t(E.hat) %*% E.hat)
  sigma2.hat <- (E2.hat / (n - r))[1,1]
  var.covar.beta.hat <- sigma2.hat * inv.XtX
  se.beta.hat <- t(t(sqrt(diag(var.covar.beta.hat))))
  Y.bar <- mean(Y)
  R2 <- 1 - (E2.hat) / (t(Y-Y.bar) %*% (Y-Y.bar))
  return(c(beta.hat[2], se.beta.hat[2], sigma2.hat, R2))
}
```

Here is my code using the built-in "lm":

```
res.bi.all <- apply(x, 1, function(xi){lm(y ~ xi)})
```

Here is my custom OLS code:

```
res.cm.all <- apply(x, 1, function(xi){apply(y, 2, GetResFromCustomLinReg, xi)})
```

When I run this example with the values given above, I get:

```
> system.time( res.bi.all <- apply(x, 1, function(xi){lm(y ~ xi)}) )
   user  system elapsed
  2.526   0.000   2.528
> system.time( res.cm.all <- apply(x, 1, function(xi){apply(y, 2, GetResFromCustomLinReg, xi)}) )
   user  system elapsed
  4.561   0.000   4.561
```

(And, naturally, it gets worse when increasing N, X and Y.)

Of course, "lm" has the nice property of "automatically" fitting separately each column of the response matrix (y~xi), while I have to use "apply" Y times (for each yi~xi). But is this the only reason why my code is slower? Does one of you know how to improve this?

(Sorry for such a long question, but I really tried to provide a minimal, yet comprehensive example.)

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 2.12.2 (2011-02-25)
Platform: x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu (64-bit)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have a look at the `fastLm()` function in the [RcppArmadillo](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rcpp.armadillo.html) package on CRAN.  There is also a similar `fastLm()` in [RcppGSL](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/rcpp.gsl.html) which preceded this -- but you probably want the [Armadillo](http://arma.sf.net)-based solution.  I have some slides in older presentations (on HPC with R) that show the speed gains.

Also note the hint in the help page about better 'pivoted' approaches than the straight inverse of X'X which can matter with degenerate model matrices.

Comment: Thanks a lot Dirk! (sorry for my late reply). However, I found that using "lm.fit" directly was quicker than "fastLmPure" (which is itself, quicker than "fastLm"). Thus, can I add my answer to my own question?

Comment: @wfoolhill Definitely yes. This is too important thing to left in comments.

Comment: i had the same experience. fastLmPure was about the same speed as lm.fit. is this expected? i tested on X = matrix(rnorm(1e8),1e6,100);y = rnorm(1e6);

Comment: `lm.fit` is fast, but does not construct or return a covariance matrix so you cannot do inference. But the `fastLm*` variants do.

Answer (score 4):

Following Marek's comment, below are the results of comparing the built-in functions "lm" and "lm.fit", my own function, "fastLm" and "fastLmPure" from the package RcppArmadillo:

```
> system.time( res1 <- apply(x, 1, function(xi){lm(y ~ xi)}) )
   user  system elapsed
  2.859   0.005   2.865
> system.time( res2 <- apply(x, 1, function(xi){apply(y, 2, GetResFromCustomLinReg, xi)}) )
   user  system elapsed
  4.620   0.004   4.626
> system.time( res3 <- apply(x, 1, function(xi){lm.fit(x=cbind(1,xi), y=y)}) )
   user  system elapsed
  0.454   0.004   0.458
> system.time( res4 <- apply(x, 1, function(xi){apply(y, 2, fastLm, x=cbind(1,xi))}) )
   user  system elapsed
  2.279   0.005   2.283
> system.time( res5 <- apply(x, 1, function(xi){apply(y, 2, fastLmPure, cbind(1,xi))}) )
   user  system elapsed
  1.053   0.003   1.056
```

However, be careful when comparing these numbers. The differences are due not only to the different implementations, but also to which results are effectively computed:

```
> names(res1$p1)
 [1] "coefficients"  "residuals"     "effects"       "rank"        
 [5] "fitted.values" "assign"        "qr"            "df.residual" 
 [9] "xlevels"       "call"          "terms"         "model"       
> # res2 (from my own custom function) returns the estimate of beta, its standard error, the estimate of sigma and the R^2
> names(res3$p1)
[1] "coefficients"  "residuals"     "effects"       "rank"        
[5] "fitted.values" "assign"        "qr"            "df.residual" 
> names(res4$p1$out1)
[1] "coefficients"  "stderr"        "df"            "fitted.values"
[5] "residuals"     "call"        
> names(res5$p1$out1)
[1] "coefficients" "stderr"       "df"
```

For instance, we may prefer to use "lm.fit" over "lm", but if we need the R^2, we will have to compute it by ourselves. Idem, we may want to use "fastLm" over "lm", but if we want the estimate of sigma, we will have to compute it by ourselves. And computing such things with a custom R function may not be very efficient (compare to what is done by "lm").

In the light of all this, I will keep using "lm" for the moment, but indeed Dirk's comment about "fastLm" is good advice (that's why I chose his answer, as it should be of interest for other people).

Comment: There's also `lsfit` which also has less overhead than `lm` and is meant to be called directly (`lm.fit` recommends against direct use in its help page; not sure why).